# Cannot compile openjdk7 source code on CentOS6.5

Tags: centos, java

I was trying to compile openjdk source code on CentOS6.5, and I got the following error message while running make. if anybody can help? thanks in advance.

software version: 
JDK: openjdk-7u40-fcs-src-b43-26_aug_2013
OS: Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

make[6]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/openjdk/build/linux-amd64-debug/hotspot/outputdir/linux_amd64_compiler2/jvmg'
cd linux_amd64_compiler2/jvmg && ./test_gamma
Using java runtime at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/jre
./gamma: relocation error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.33.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so: symbol JVM_FindClassFromCaller, version SUNWprivate_1.1 not defined in file libjvm.so with link time reference
make[5]: *** [jvmg] Error 127
make[5]: Leaving directory`/usr/local/openjdk/build/linux-amd64-debug/hotspot/outputdir'
make[4]: *** [generic_build2] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/openjdk/hotspot/make'
make[3]: *** [jvmg] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory`/usr/local/openjdk/hotspot/make'
make[2]: *** [hotspot-build] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/openjdk'
make[1]: *** [generic_debug_build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory`/usr/local/openjdk'

Comment: I ended up this issue by upgrading my JDK version to 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Editor file hotspot/make/linux/Makefile,and delete all the `test_gamma` in Makefile.
It past!

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same error when build my openjdk7 on ubuntu14.04 and I suggest you check the file 
***/usr/local/openjdk/build/linux-amd64-debug/hotspot/outputdir/linux_amd64_compiler2/jvmg/test_gamma***,
this error happens at the end of this shell script, remove those lines from the file and try it again.
hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Oracle JDK 1.6.0_45 and set it to "ALT_BOOTDIR" and "ALT_JDK_IMPORT_PATH", please do not use OpenJDK1.6